# Lotus 123 to Excel 2003 conversion

Tags: excel, lotus

I have been asked to convert some Lotus 123 wk4 files with macros to excel 2003,  I know the data will convert with most formulas.  I am wondering if there is a way to convert the lotus macros also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automatic way to convert macros.  However, LotusScript is fairly similar to VBA, so it is possible to convert, though not without quite a bit of work.  The event model is also somewhat different, so you'll have to convert these macros on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen no conversion tool to convert the macros. As others have mentioned, that's typically manual.